# How to remove the event?

Tags: c#, events

For Sample ....

SampleClass :

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public delegate void BeforeEditorHandle();
    public event BeforeEditorHandle OnBeforeEditor;
}
```

MainMethod

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SampleClass sc = new SampleClass();
        // Add Event
        sc.OnBeforeEditor +=new SampleClass.BeforeEditorHandle(sc_OnBeforeEditor);
        // Remove Event
        sc.OnBeforeEditor -= new SampleClass.BeforeEditorHandle(sc_OnBeforeEditor);

    }
```

And , if I add the event by dynamic like this ...↓

```
sc.OnBeforeEditor += () => {  };
```

Should I remove the event like ↓

```
sc.OnBeforeEditor -= () => {  };
```

But I think this is very ugly when I have too much sources in the event....
Can anybody tell me the best way to remove the event please ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your code here won't work:

> And , if I add the event by dynamic like this ...↓
>
> ```
> sc.OnBeforeEditor += () => {  };
> ```
>
> Should I remove the event like ↓
>
> ```
> sc.OnBeforeEditor -= () => {  };
> ```

This is because restating the lambda creates a new different lambda.

You need to store the old reference and use it to unsubscribe:

```
BeforeEditorHandle myHandler=() => {  }
sc.OnBeforeEditor += myHandler;

...
sc.OnBeforeEditor -= myHandler;
```

For easier unsubscribing you can collect your event handlers in a collection (For example `List<BeforeEditorHandle>`).

Comment: @Oded what did you change? I think we had an editing conflict.

Comment: Just added 4 spaces in front of your `...` :)

Answer (score 8):

You can assign the event handler/lambda to a variable which you can then subscribe and unsubscribe:

```
var myHandler = () => {  };

sc.OnBeforeEditor += myHandler;

sc.OnBeforeEditor -= myHandler;
```

Comment: You need to type `myHandler` explicitly. (`Cannot assign lambda expression to an implicitly-typed local variable`)

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx):

> It is important to notice that you
>   cannot easily unsubscribe from an
>   event if you used an anonymous
>   function to subscribe to it. To
>   unsubscribe in this scenario, it is
>   necessary to go back to the code where
>   you subscribe to the event, store the
>   anonymous method in a delegate
>   variable, and then add the delegate to
>   the event. In general, we recommend
>   that you do not use anonymous
>   functions to subscribe to events if
>   you will have to unsubscribe from the
>   event at some later point in your
>   code. For more information about
>   anonymous functions, see Anonymous
>   Functions (C# Programming Guide).